# How to write a function accepting a std::vector or std::list?

Tags: c++, list, vector, std, base-class

Bit of a simple question this one, I guess.

Vectors and lists both have push and pop functions, and - more importantly - can be iterated over:

```
for ( auto value : items )
    ...
```

std::vector and std::list don't seem to share a base class, however. The question is, therefore: How do I write a function that will accept either one (or, indeed, anything else that fits the implementation)?

```
std::list<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
DoSomething(a);
DoSomething(b);
```

I'd like to do it without overloading. If templates are used, they shouldn't cause insane error messages. For example, the following code --

```
int a;
DoSomething(a);
```

-- should result in a compile error at the call site, ***not somewhere inside the template!***

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standardisation committee tried to introduce concepts to C++0x (now C++11) to resolve the issues you raise here. They were forced to back them out late in the piece, so we'll have to wait until a future version of the standard.

Boost's [BCCL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) offers a portable interim solution. I've never used the library, so I can't vouch for or against it.

Comment: So for the next five years or so, it's just not possible? (The BCCL looks way too complicated, btw)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the stl algorithms used iterators to as a layer of abstraction from the container.

For example the `sort` takes 2 random access iterators to sort :

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
   void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
```

Most of the algorithms can be implemented using this idiom

Depending on the algorithm you plan to implement you will need to choose between the 4 types of standard iterators

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) is a link which explains wich type would be better suited

Comment: So my only option is to accept two `forward_iterator` instances? Sounds a bit awkward to me. Why can't the collections all have a base class `Iterable` that has `Begin()` and `End()` functions? Sigh.

Comment: Most of the Standard Template Library (STL) is built on templates rather than inheritance. One of the reasons why you don't have an `Iteratable` is because the inheritance graph would need to be complex to accomodate the 4 types of iterator.